# Help in simplifying an alternating factorial

Tags: factorial

What is $\dfrac{(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)\cdots}{(n-2)(n-4)(n-6)\cdots}$ ?

Can it be simplified in terms of $n$? I could not convert it into a factorial form.

Plz solve

Comment: I don't think so except if you know $n$. You can rewrite it is a shorter way with double factorials as $\dfrac{(n-1)!!}{(n-2)!!}$.

Comment: There are many ways to write this in terms of factorials. One is $\frac{(n-1)!!}{(n-2)!!}$. Another can be to split the cases of $n$ odd and even. If $n$ is even $n=2k$, then we get that it is equal to $\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{n}[(n/2-1)!]^2}$. If $n=2k+1$ is odd you get $\frac{2^{n-1}[(n-1)/2!]^2}{(n-1)!}$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written in terms of the Gamma function.

When $n$ is even,
$$
{\frac { \left( n-1 \right) !!}{ \left( n-2 \right) !!}}={\frac {
2\;\Gamma \left( n/2+1/2 \right) }{\sqrt {\pi}\;\Gamma
 \left( n/2 \right) }}
$$
and when $n$ is odd,
$$
{\frac { \left( n-1 \right) !!}{ \left( n-2 \right) !!}}={\frac {\Gamma \left( n/2+1/2 \right) \sqrt {\pi}}{\Gamma \left( n/
2 \right) }}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n=2m$. We have $k=(n-2)(n-4)\dots2=2^{m-1}(m-1)!$ and so the given expression is $$\frac{(2m-1)!}{k^2}=\frac{2m-1}{2^{2m-2}}\ {2m-2\choose m-1}$$

If $n=2m+1$ we have $h=(n-1)(n-3)\dots2=2^mm!$ and so the given expression is $$\frac{h^2}{(2m)!}=\frac{2^{2m}}{{2m\choose m}}$$